# How to implement singly linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am trying to populate my linked list in C, but id does not word how 
I want to. I want to keep a pointer "p" and keep adding to the list with the same pointer. However when I try to print, it prints only the data of the head!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
}node;

int main(){
   node *head = NULL;
   head =  malloc(sizeof(node));
   if(head==NULL){
     printf("ta foirer quelque chose frero!");
     return 1;
   }
   (*head).data=3;
   (*head).next=NULL;

   node *p = NULL;

  p = (node*) head->next;
  p =  malloc(sizeof(node));
  p->data = 5;

  p->next = NULL;
  p= (node *)p->next;

  int i=0;
  while(i<5){
    p =  malloc(sizeof(node));
    i++;
    p->data = i;
    p->next=NULL;
    p= (node *)p->next;
  }


  p = head;

  while(p){
    printf("\n%d",p->data);
    p =(node*) p->next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am getting as output

```
3
```

and I am expecting to get

```
3
5
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node node;

void insert(node* h, int v) {
    node* tmp = h;

    while(tmp->next)
        tmp = tmp->next;
    node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = v;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    tmp->next = newnode;
}

int main(){
   node *head = NULL;
   head =  malloc(sizeof(node));
   if(head==NULL){
     printf("ta foirer quelque chose frero!");
     return 1;
   }
   head->data=3;
   head->next = NULL;


   node *p = NULL;

  insert(head, 5);
  int i=0;
  while(i<5){
    insert(head, i++);
  }


  p = head;

  while(p){
    printf("%d\n",p->data);
    p = p->next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If you notice, I changed the layout of your code a bit, and made it cleaner. What you needed was to traverse to find the **node** that appears before the **place to add the new node**, which in this case is the end. Usually this is a separate pointer in a different struct that contains the head and this is called the **tail** of a linked list. You were simply not keeping track of **where** to really add the node. This insert function above does that.

Comment: If you keep a pointer to `tail` (the end node), you no longer have to iterate over the list each time you insert a new node `:)`

Comment: Yes, I didn't fully explain everything hoping maybe he'd go out of his way and figure out what the tail is used for.